# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send' In my Discord Command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

If anyone could explain where i have gone wrong with this it would be extremely helpful, Below i've provided the error and the code. Thanks :)
If anyone could walk me through on how to fix it or clearly outline where i went wrong would be nice, i can't for the life of me seem to figure out what is missing from it and why the embed is missing the value?

```
Ignoring exception in command ip:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*name*\Desktop\Sanitary SB\Sanitary.py", line 85, in ip
    ctx.send(embed=em)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\*name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*name*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

````
@Sanitary.command()
async def ip(self, ctx, *, ipaddr: str = "1.3.3.7"):
        r = requests.get(f'http://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/{ipaddr}')
        em = discord.Embed(color=0x00000)
        geo = r.json()
        fields = [
            {'name': 'IP', 'value': geo['query']},
            {'name': 'ipType', 'value': geo['ipType']},
            {'name': 'Country', 'value': geo['country']},
            {'name': 'City', 'value': geo['city']},
            {'name': 'Continent', 'value': geo['continent']},
            {'name': 'Country', 'value': geo['country']},
            {'name': 'IPName', 'value': geo['ipName']},
            {'name': 'ISP', 'value': geo['isp']},
            {'name': 'Latitute', 'value': geo['lat']},
            {'name': 'Longitude', 'value': geo['lon']},
            {'name': 'Org', 'value': geo['org']},
            {'name': 'Region', 'value': geo['region']},
            {'name': 'Status', 'value': geo['status']},
        ]
        for field in fields:
            if field['value']:
                em.add_field(name=field['name'], value=field['value'], inline=True)
        return await ctx.send(embed=em)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `self` from the commands function parameters, this isn't in a class, so `ctx` is actually the string that is given, furthermore you should remove the `*` since functions in discord.py are fairly different and are assigned in order of spaces in the command (if you are using `discord.ext.commands`, which you are.)

Comment: No problem at all :)